# Linq get Distinct ToDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda, distinct

need help to only select/get distinct entries based on i.Code.
There are duplicates and thus I'm getting an error in my expression "*An item with the same key has already been added.*"

```
 var myDictionary = dbContext.myDbTable
            .Where(i => i.shoesize>= 4)
            .OrderBy(i => i.Code)              
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i);
```

Have tried to use Select and/or Distinct in different combinations and also by themselves but am still getting the same error

```
var myDictionary= dbContext.myDbTable
            .Where(i => i.shoesize>= 4)
            .OrderBy(i => i.Code)
            //.Select(i => i)
            //.Distinct()
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i);
```

Can anybody help? C#

UPDATE: If there are multiple objects with the same code I only want to add the first object(with that particular code) to myDictionary.

Comment: I guess you need a Comparer for `.Distinct()`. Your items might have same `Code` but different other properties. With default comparer, those are not considered same by linq.

Comment: No, I only want one entry per code (it's a duplicate, henc I only want one entry per code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By dividing it and creating a list first it worked as compared to when it was all bundled up into one linq, guess the First() needed it to be in a list before being able to make it into a dict.

```
var firstLinq = dbContext.myDbTable
           .Where(i => i.shoesize>= 4)
           .ToList();
```

then

```
 var finalLinq = fromConcurWithDuplicates
            .GroupBy(i => i.Code)
            .Select(i => i.First())
            .ToList()
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can group by `Code` and select the first item from each group (which is equivalent to distinct):

```
var myDictionary = dbContext.myDbTable
            .Where(i => i.shoesize >= 4)      // filter
            .GroupBy(x => x.Code)             // group by Code
            .Select(g => g.First())           // select 1st item from each group           
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i);
```

You don't need the `OrderBy` since `Dictionary`s represent an unordered collection. If you need an ordered dictionary you could use [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Am getting this error:
  .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: What does the table look like? You'll need to share more info to solve that issue @JoBo

Comment: @JoBo you could try pulling all the data into memory using `ToList` after `GroupBy`. Something like this might work: `dbContext.myDbTable.Where(i => i.shoesize >= 4).GroupBy(x => x.Code).ToList().Select(g => g.First()).ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that what you are looking for is [`.DistinctBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) (available in .NET 6), which lets you specify which property to distinct the elements in your collection by:

```
var myDictionary= dbContext.myDbTable
            .Where(i => i.shoesize>= 4)
            .DistinctBy(i => i.Code)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Code, i => i);
```

Comment: Am using .Net Core 3.1 so DistinctBy is not available it seems.

Comment: @JoBo Ah, okay.